# KeyListener and Game Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, enums, keyboard

i got a problem and i hope i can describe it to you guys beautifully.

i have this game i am creating

like all games i have this update method in a thread

```
update();
```

and also i have implemented a key listener;

now heres my problem, i have a ButtonState enum:

```
enum ButtonState{down,up}
```

i have a KeyboardState class:

```
KeyBoardState{
 public ButtonState A=ButtonState.up;
}
```

i have a Keyboard class that has a static KeyboardState

```
KeyBoard{
    public static KeyboardState state=new KeyboardState();
}
```

in my KeyListener its like this:

```
keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A)KeyBoard.getKeyBoardState().W=ButtonState.down;
}

keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A)KeyBoard.getKeyBoardState().W=ButtonState.up;
}
```

now in my update code its like this

```
KeyBoardState current=new KeyBoardState();
KeyBoardState old=new KeyboardState();

update(){

    current=Keyboard.state;
    //here both current and old become buttonstate.down when pressed and vice versa
    if(current.a==ButtonState.down && old.a==ButtonState.up){
     //do
    }
    old = current;
}
```

my problem is this, whenever i press A, both current.a and old.a becomes  ButtonState.down and same when i release it. so the code never goes to //do.

can i make it that KeyListener is in the same thread as the game? if so how?

Comment: You problem is that both `current` and `old` are pointing to same instance of `KeyboardState`. Make copy of it when assigning to `old`.

Comment: @talex sorry, edited

Comment: you don't get what talex is saying. The moment `old = current;` is executed, both references show to same object. Instead it should be e.g. `old.a = current.a`

Comment: So then if u were to have B C D E F...then i would need to do that to each one of them? Because thats what i plan on doing. Can u suggest a better way of doing what i want to be done?

Comment: Firstly I don't think overly abstracting everything is a good approach, and for anything simple I would write all input related logic inside listeners.

Comment: But if you want to stick with it, just let KeyboardState implement Cloneable interface and call clone method on it.

Comment: Oh ill check on that....the reason i do these is to somehow immittate XNA's keyboardstate